# Cart Refresh Options

Tags: b2b-commerce, b2b, b2b-lex

I am trying to create a way for storefront users to easily **restart checkout** and refresh their cart in a B2B Lightning Store.

I am currently displaying a button through a screen flow component which grabs the cartId. From there I am grabbing the current checkout session and setting the state back to *Start*. If there is already an order made and associated with the checkout session it is deleted.

I know that when your cart items are edited, it also refreshes your checkout session id so I try increasing and decreasing a cart item by one. I have not been able to successfully start the checkout process, go through to the billing screen, exit the checkout, and refresh to start a new checkout. If my cart refresh button is clicked it will still pickup at the billing screen again.

Do I need to create a new checkout session? If so, how does it need to interact with a Background Operation Id? Can this be done declaratively?

Comment: Hello Brian - There are not many B2B Lightning experts on SFSE, but may I suggest you amend your to expand on what you mean by restart checkout & refresh cart? Is this some re-ordering or simply cancelling a checkout?

Comment: By restart checkout I mean that nothing about their cart changes, all items stay in the cart, but the checkout process starts back at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can, and yes, declaratively, it requires a new Checkout Session. **Except** for when the cart is closed - which already created the order. If the cart is closed, you should look at re-order instead.

Given the time of the question, I will assume this is using Commerce Checkout Flow.

You can add [Cancel Cart Async Operation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_b2b_comm_actions_cancel_cart_async_operation.htm&type=5) and then initiate again with [Checkout Session Action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_b2b_comm_actions_checkout_session_action.htm&type=5).

This is what one [example Checkout flow](https://github.com/forcedotcom/b2b-commerce-on-lightning-quickstart/blob/master/examples/checkout-main/flows/Checkout_Main_Checkout.flow#L62-L80) does.